# Showing that automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has a specific form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm to show that all automorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_n\to \mathbb{Z}_n$ are of the form $\phi(m) = km$,

where $k\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and the greatest common divisor of n and k, $gcd(k,n) = 1$.

I was thinking that I could show that if $\phi(m) = km$, wasn't on the specified form, then it wouldn't be an automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

First of all I'm uncertain as to whether I have to prove that all homomorphisms $\psi: \mathbb{Z}_n \to
\mathbb{Z}_n$ are of the form $\psi(m) = km$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}_n$.

But then I thought: if I show that $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$ is on the form $\phi(m) = km$, where  $gcd(k,n) \neq 1$ (no need to show that $k\in \mathbb{Z}_n$, since $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z} \to k \in \mathbb{Z}_n$), then $\phi$ isn't bijective and hence isn't an automorphism, have I then shown the original claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=\psi(1)$. Then, for each $m\in\mathbb{Z}_n$,\begin{align}\psi(m)&=\psi(\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{m\text{ times}})\\&=\overbrace{k+k+\cdots+k}^{m\text{ times}}\\&=km.\end{align}So, yes, every endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has this form and your approach is correct: now all you need to prove is that $\psi$ is an automorphism if and only if $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

Comment: But I can also prove that by proving that if $gcd(k,n)\neq 1$ then $\psi$ isn't an automorphism, right? Like let $gcd(k,n) = n$, then $\psi(a) = \psi(b) = 0 \hspace{2pt} \forall a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and so $\psi$ isn't an automorphism. Now let $gcd(k,n) = x<n$. Then for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n$, $ax = n$ and then let $m=\frac{ax}{k} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and so $\psi(m) = mk = \frac{ax}{k}k = ax = n = 0 = \psi(n)$ and so $\psi$ isn't an automorphism. Is this enough?

Comment: @Mathaniel It's more than enough. There is no need to make a distinction between the cases $\gcd(k,n)=n$ and $\gcd(k,n)<n$, as long as you use somewhere the fact that $\gcd(k,n)>1$.

Comment: And can I fix that by just saying $gcd(k,n) = x$ with $1<x<n$ without further justification?

Comment: @Mathaniel If $\gcd(k,n)=x>1$, then $\psi\left(\frac nx\right)=k\frac nx=\frac kxn=0$. But $\frac nx\neq0$. Therefore, $\psi$ is not an automorphism.